# Unable to install

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, installation

Unable to install SQL Server 2008 in windows 8.1 64 bits it asks for .Net Framework 2.0 but I have already installed .Net Framework 4.5 with the OS.

Comment: Can you please locate setup log files and post content of Summary.txt. The location would be C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log

Answer (score 4):

Have you installed .net framework 2 (part of 3.5) from Programs and Features?

[image]

This is *separate* to .net 4.5...

Comment: Just in case more instructions are needed, [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) tells how to install it.  On Server 2012/R2 the process [is a bit different](http://www.danielclasson.com/install-net-framework-35-server-2012/)

Comment: This is not an answer you must ask user to look at contents of summary.txt why it failed

Comment: @shanky this is the reason. An older version SQL on a newer OS

Comment: I guess this link-- https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2681562/en-gb?wa=wsignin1.0  has more details and would highlihht every thing required to install sql server on windows 8